Why isn't NO considered combustible?
According to this (and a bunch of other sources), NO (nitric oxide) is not combustible. But that  same source says NO rapidly reacts with O2 to produce NO2, which I thought was the definition of combustion: being rapidly oxidized by oxygen. So why isn't it considered "combustible"?

You should search properly before asking. // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion

NO doesn't react nearly that rapidly. While it can be oxidised to NO2, it's prone to decompose to elements.

Yes, so why aren't NOx species considered combustible according to Wikipedia? It doesn't explain.

Use a good dictionary like Merriam Webster, can you add the definition of the word combustible in the question: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/combustible

"a usually rapid chemical process (such as oxidation) that produces heat and usually light" According to this, NO qualifies, but I'm not sure Merriam-Webster is the best source for definitions of chemistry terms.

Well, I was actually surprised, but as you could notice on Wikipedia, NO is explosive. If you tried to make NO flame, it would explode, breaking down to N2, instead of combusting.

But it can also be oxidized to make NO2, as my link says. I'd argue that being capable of combustion makes it combustible, even if it can also explode.

According to MSDS of nitric oxide, it is noncombustible but is a strong oxidizer that accelerates the burning of other substances material

That's where some of the confusion stems from: NO can act as both a reducing and an oxidizing agent. It has a free electron, so it's desperate to either lose its free electron or gain an electron to pair it up with.

Combustion is general scientific term. The OP originally asked, what is meant by combustible. A typical dictionary definition is:

Capable of being burnt or consumed by fire, fit for burning, burnable.

So let us look at the detailed definition of combustion from an authentic source (behind paywall), the multivolume Oxford English Dictionary. It is actually better than many chemistry dictionaries.
Combustion:

The ordinary term in scientific use.   As all ordinary combustion
consists in the energetic combination of a body with oxygen, with
evolution of heat and light, this was alone contemplated in earlier
definitions of the term; but since it has been known that similar
phenomena attend the combination of other elements, e.g. that of
hydrogen and metals with chlorine, bromine, and iodine, combustion has
been defined more generally as ‘The development of light and heat
accompanying chemical combination’. internal combustion engine, etc.:
Formerly, oxygen was regarded as essentially the supporter of
combustion, the bodies which burned in it being called combustibles.
Afterwards the former term was extended to all substances capable of
forming vapours in which others can burn, as chlorine, bromine,
iodine, sulfur; but since the same substance may sometimes act in both
capacities, and since the vapours in question are actually consumed in
the process, as truly as the so-called ‘combustible’, the distinction
has gradually become obsolete. (Watts, etc.)

If you want to be esoteric, $\ce{NO}$ may be termed as comburent. A comburent causes combustion of certain materials. Nitric oxide is not combustible in the sense that it will not combine with oxygen with the emission of visible light or large amount of heat. $\ce{NO}$  is instantly oxidized to a brown colored gas $\ce{NO2}$. One can further split hairs with relatively cold flames but this should be enough at this stage.

Does the fact that NO can act as an oxidizing agent have anything to
do with it not being considered "combustible", or is the fact that NO
doesn't release light or heat when reacted with oxygen like the
quintessential combustion reaction the only reason?

Mostly the latter. It does not react with oxygen with the emission of light or significant amount of heat.
Note that molecules do not care what labels humans have given them.

Thanks!  Does the fact that NO can act as an oxidizing agent have anything to do with it not being considered "combustible", or is the fact that NO doesn't release light or heat when reacted with oxygen like the quintessential combustion reaction the only reason?

The nitrogen oxides are all endothermic compounds with relatively small energy differences among them. Similar behavior is seen among higher oxidation states of many elements such as chlorine, manganese, iron , chromium .

Combustible gases form a flame with oxygen, when ignited. NO does not, nor it can get ignited.
